# Android, Windows Metro apps and Windows Desktop

Tags: android, windows, windows-8

Hello everyone and thanks for viewing this question :)

I am an **indie to-be-developer** and want to make apps for android, windows 8 desktop and metro.

After having read through a lot of forums and blogs, I believe that perhaps to make the best looking(native-feel) apps I have to learn

1. Java for Android
2. HTML,CSS and JS for Metro
3. Something else for Windows desktop

What I need your help in is, whether there is any **one particular language** which I should start with which will make my journey better ?

By app I mean something to do with **sharing and transferring of files.**

**P.S. Read that Python might be perfect !**

Do you agree ? Please suggest something.

Comment: do you know any programming languages? Java is a pretty decent first language to start with... and is on your list of burn downs..

Comment: If you want to make an app for sharing files, you need to decide a lot of things. What kind of app (mobile or web), target platforms, sharing protocol, how and where to store files, architecture, etc, etc. We can't make these decisions for you, because they depend on personal knowledge, preference, and resources. Figure out what you want to do, because you're the only one who can know that, then ask questions if you have problems getting it done. I would suggest that you take a read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask).

Comment: @EsotericScreenName : Thanks for your reply. I am making a mobile and desktop app. I would definitely keep in mind the points while asking a question next time. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tanis alluded to, you'll need to determine where your goals are in terms of "rich functionality versus maximum reach" - and from your "best looking (native-feel)" comment, I'd say you're leaning toward "rich"

Pure HTML5/CSS/JavaScript will give you the greatest reach because of browser ubiquity, BUT you can still use HTML5/CSS/JS for *native* development for modern Windows 8 applications and via [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) for Android and other mobile devices. Having one code base AND supporting native features across those platforms would be difficult, if not impossible, but with the right design and architecture you should be able to get a great amount of reuse of your HTML/CSS/JS assets.

Another option, since you've mentioned Windows Desktop as well, is to use WPF and XAML with C#. You can build native Windows desktop applications with it, and those same technologies (XAML/C#) are one of the three primary development options (along with HTML5/JS and C++/XAML) for modern Windows 8 (nee Metro) applications. For the Android piece of it, Xamarin's [Mono for Android](http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid) lets you reuse many of your C#/.NET assets for deploying native applications to Android (and they have [MonoTouch](http://xamarin.com/monotouch) as well to add iOS to your arsenal!)

As for Python, productive and powerful language, and great for backend services - like the plumbing for sharing and transferring files - but it wouldn't be my tool of choice for building mobile apps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the highest level of cross-platform compatibility, a web-app (typically HTML, CSS, and JS) would be best. Making a web app will help ensure that your app works on nearly every device with a web browser, and you only need to maintain one code base.

The trade-off is that you often lose some features, such as the use of some of a phone's sensors.

If you want to make native apps for each, then I would suggest Java (particularly for Android) or C/C++ (particularly for desktop environments).
Python is an excellent starting language as well (and [codeacademy](http://codeacademy.com) has some great tutorials), but isn't as directly applicable to app development as Java or C/C++.